# Flutter pub get running in wrong directory?

Tags: windows, flutter

I created a new flutter project using flutter create. The path to `pubspec.yaml` is `D:\dev\flutter\example\`

But when I run flutter run in my projects, it gives an error: `pubspec.yaml` not found in `D:\dev\flutter\`

Why is flutter pub get running in the parent directory of my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. my bad i didnt look at my pubspec which contained

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  responsive_framework:
    path: ../
```

the 'path' was causing it to run pub get in parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

Move to the folder you have recently created-

```
cd example
```

Then run "`flutter run`" from that folder.

Comment: thats what im doing.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project directory by:

```
cd D:\dev\flutter\example
```

Then run:

```
flutter clean
flutter run
```

Comment: didnt help, sorry